# FeathersJS Mongoose: PUT makes "createdAt" and "updatedAt" disappear

Tags: mongoose-schema, feathersjs

I have a service (I didn't attach any hook yet) with the following mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const restaurantSchema = new Schema({
  text: { type: String, required: true }
}, { timestamps: true });

const restaurantModel = mongoose.model('restaurant', restaurantSchema);

module.exports = restaurantModel;
```

The problem is: whenever I send a PUT request, both `createdAt` and `updatedAt` disappear from my object.

Shouldn't `timestamps: true` make mongoose keep the timestamps and update the value of `updatedAt`?

Comment: PUT is supposed to replace the entire record. Maybe `PATCH` is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Daff Thanks, you are right. PATCH is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daff [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581987/feathersjs-mongoose-put-makes-createdat-and-updatedat-disappear?noredirect=1#comment66506574_39581987), that is just the expected behavior for PUT. Reading the repo, I found that what causes this behavior is the `overwrite` option. It is set to [true by default](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-mongoose/blob/master/src/service.js#L23), causing updates to completely replace the current object leaving no timestamps.

I should really use PATCH to update only certain fields and keep the timestamps.